# Determining which layer in raster stack is first to meet condition using R?

Tags: raster, r, function, stack

I want to analyze a raster stack and determine the first layer in the stack that meets a condition for every pixel.

Here's a reproducible code example generating rasters and making a stack.

```
# Generate stack of random values
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- r4 <-r5 <- r6 <- r7 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- rpois(ncell(r1), 1)
r2[] <- rpois(ncell(r2), 1)
r3[] <- rpois(ncell(r3), 1)
r4[] <- rpois(ncell(r4), 1)
r5[] <- rpois(ncell(r5), 1)
r6[] <- rpois(ncell(r6), 1)
r7[] <- rpois(ncell(r7), 1)

# stack them
s <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7)
```

I want to analyze this stack to determine which layer is the first to meet a condition like: "Value = 1 for 3 consecutive layers" or "2 of last 3 layers have value = 1", for example.

Can you think of any function to do this?

If I run rasterToPoints I can convert the stack into a matrix with columns representing each layer, this may make things easier.

Once I determine the correct layer corresponding to each pixel, I then want an output raster with that layer number as the value for each pixel.

A somewhat similar question has been previously posted as [Counting layer number of raster stack with value under some conditions and write it into output layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232296), though that's counting the number of layers that meet a condition.

Comment: Are all your conditions functions of a single pixel-stack? Write a function that returns the index of the element that satisfies a condition given a vector of pixels and then use `calc` to compute that over your stack and then find the minimum of that?

Comment: Yes, everything references a single pixel at a time. For now I've: 
Run rasterToPoints to create a data frame of raster values
Looped through that with a while loop to find the first entry that satisfies a condition:

test<-as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(s))

for (j in 1:nrow(test)){
      i=7
       while ((test[j,i] + test[j,i-1] + test[j,i-2] + test[j,i-3] + test[j,i-4]) < 2) {
       i <- i+1
  }
    if (i==(ncol(test)-1)) i<-0
    test$first[j]<-i
 }

Any help vectorizing that or running that on the raster stack itself would be helpful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can write a function that works on a single vector of values then you can use `calc` to run that over a raster. For example here's a function that returns the position of the first run of three ones in a vector, or NA if no run of three ones exists:

```
threeones <- function(x){
    r = rle(x) # use rle to count runs of things
    got31s = r$lengths >=3 & r$values == 1 # any runs of three 1s?
    n = NA
    if(any(got31s)){
        pos = min(which(got31s)) # get the first run of three
        n = sum(r$lengths[1:(pos)]) - r$lengths[pos]+1 # get pos of first 1
    }
    return(n)
}
```

You can then test this with some test values:

```
> tv = list(c(1,1,1,0,2,3), c(0,1,2,1,2,3), c(0,1,1,1,0,0), c(0,0,0,0,1,1), c(0,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1))
> lapply(tv,threeones)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] 2
```

Which all looks good. Now run it on your test stack:

```
> s31 = calc(s,threeones)
```

and check some locations. At position 6,6 there's a sequence of four ones starting at layer 3:

```
> s[6,6]
     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4 layer.5 layer.6 layer.7
[1,]       3       0       1       1       1       1       3
```

and `s31` at that point is....

```
> s31[6,6]
[1] 3
>
```

There's probably a better implementation of my `threeones` function (its a bit fiddly and there's always nuisance edge casess) but I think the important thing is to show you how to run over pixels using `calc`.

Note that `threeones` *isnt* vectorised, and doesn't have to be for `calc` to work.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I'm not very good with writing functions so this definitely helps. I worked out a way using a for and while loop - this is probably much faster than that.